# What's the features of the symbol table of C language and java?

Tags: compilation

In the compiling process, both C and Java use symbol tables. What are their features and differences? And how do they respectively store the parameters of functions? (For C language, can take gcc as an example.)

I think the differences come from that Java is object-oriented while C can manipulate memory. But I cannot find related information from Internet.

Comment: Get a book on compiler construction.

Comment: @n.m. could be an AI May I ask which book it should be? None of the books I found on specifically talk about C and java compilation.

Comment: There is nothing specific about C and Java.